# Meaning of the proverb: "No man is an island entire of itself"

Tags: meaning, quotations, literature

What's the meaning of the proverb "No man is an island entire of itself" by John Donne?

Comment: It's not really a proverb but rather the first line of a poem: http://web.cs.dal.ca/~johnston/poetry/island.html . Also, I'd recommend thinking through what the words mean.

Comment: @virmaior It's also considered a proverb, given that is well known, used often, and expresses a 'truth' based on common sense/experience.  Many sources list it as a proverb.  Just because it comes from a poem doesn't mean it's not a proverb - given that all proverbs originated **somewhere** (many from religious texts; does the fact a proverb came from a bible verse make it no longer a proverb?).  Also, given that the OP lists the author, I'm sure they probably know the source...

Comment: @virmaior: It's not the ***first*** line of a poem. That "poem" is the third paragraph of the (very poetic) prose composition [Meditation XVII](http://www.luminarium.org/sevenlit/donne/meditation17.php). I wouldn't hesitate to call it a prose poem, but there really should be a link to the  entire composition in these comments.

Answer (score 2):

From [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/no-man-is-an-island.html):

> **Meaning**
>
> Human beings do not thrive when isolated from others. Donne was a Christian but this concept is shared by other religions, principally Buddhism.
>
> **Origin**
>
> This is a quotation from John Donne (1572-1631). It appears in *Devotions upon emergent occasions and seuerall steps in my sicknes - Meditation XVII*, 1624:
>
> "All mankind is of one author, and is one volume; when one man dies, one chapter is not torn out of the book, but translated into a better language; and every chapter must be so translated...As therefore the bell that rings to a sermon, calls not upon the preacher only, but upon the congregation to come: so this bell calls us all: but how much more me, who am brought so near the door by this sickness....No man is an island, entire of itself...any man's death diminishes me, because I am involved in mankind; and therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls; it tolls for thee."

The quote is also listed in Phrase Finders [list of proverbs](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/proverbs.html)

Often, the phrase will be shortened to simply "No man is an island" when used as a proverb.

Comment: While not directly related to the question, Robert Heinlein's "Stranger in a Strange Land" includes a quote along the lines of "No man is an island, but we make damn good peninsulas" to reinforce the idea that a small social circle is not inferior to a broader association with people.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, first of all, "No man is an Island, entire on itself" is not a proverb!.

It is a poem by John Donne, follow this [link](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/no-man-is-an-island/) for the full poem.

Secondly, what you are asking about is a "Quote", when you take a small part of a speech or text and use it to emphasize a point/fact or convey a message, it is called a quote.

In the case of your question John Donne's poem ' No Man is an Island '.

What does the quote mean : when John Donne says " No man is an Island, entire on itself" he means that no man is all by himself, everyone's life is linked to a lot of other people directly or indirectly and you cannot claim to survive by yourself as there will be always some external contribution whether you like it or not.

Comment: "A proverb (from Latin: proverbium) is a simple and concrete saying, popularly known and repeated, that expresses a truth based on common sense or the practical experience of humanity. They are often metaphorical."  It doesn't matter where the phrase originated (in this case, a poem), it's still a proverb so long as it is known and repeated, and expresses a 'truth' - all of which are fulfilled by the given quote.

Comment: In short, if you're going to correct someone, correct them correctly.  While the actual **answer** (once you skip past all the aggressive commenting about how wrong the OP supposedly is) is correct, I downvoted due to tone and all the unnecessary/incorrect corrections.

Comment: @Doc Forgive my tone, I hope it was not offending in anyway, if it was, my apologies, the phrase/quote/proverb is self explanatory, but since the user asked for an explanation, I assumed that the user might be a beginner, so I thought it would be good to point out the difference between a quote and a proverb before going into the meaning of the proverb. I was not trying to be judgmental, just wanted to be helpful.

Comment: While you say that that link points to the "full poem", [it doesn't.](http://www.luminarium.org/sevenlit/donne/meditation17.php) That's just the third part out of four.